# Undefined Index: Stripe Token when integrating Stripe payment into website PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have been trying to integrate Stripe into my website by following the instructions provided in stripe docs. However, when it is run, the following errors show up.

Notice: Undefined index: stripeToken

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Must provide source or customer.'

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Charge the user's card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => 1000,
"currency" => "usd",
"description" => "Example charge",
"source" => $token,
)); 


<form action="shop.php" method="POST">
<script
 src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
 data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 data-amount="1000"
 data-name="Example"
 data-description="Widget"
 data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
 data-locale="auto">
</script>
</form>
```

The keys have been changed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you submit stripeToken to this file?

Comment: @JimL That was one thing I was confused about because I could not find it in the Stripe Docs and it wasn't provided in the given code.

Comment: The stripe checkout code should handle showing a credit card form, obtaining a token and passing it to your shop.php file. Do you get the form? Can you open the dev console in your browser, turn on logging in the network tab and see if you can see any errors, maybe the request for shop.php shows something that's wrong